# How to initialise a python module?

Tags: python

I have a python module ('my_module.py') and in it two functions 'A' and 'B'.

They both require a 3rd module (say pandas).

Is there a way to load pandas as part of the module so it'll be accessible to both functions? (trying to avoid importing pandas per function call...)

Or do I have to convert this into a package and load pandas as part of the **init**? (trying to avoid that since I don't want an extra directory...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `import pandas` at the start of the module.

It will be imported (and initialized) when `my_module.py` is imported or run, and it will be available for both functions. If several modules use `pandas`, `import` it at the start of each one - it will be imported only once per interpreter session.

Mockup example of `mymodule.py`:

```
import pandas

def A(foo):
    return pandas.do_something(foo)

def B(bar):
    return pandas.do_something_else(bar)
```

Comment: I tried putting 'import pandas as pd' in the begining of my module but keep getting: NameError: global name 'pd' is not defined

Comment: @user2808117: You need to do that outside of any function, at the top level of the module.

Comment: for some reason one of the parameters passed to the functions triggered that error and it wasn't an imported related one. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use `import pandas` in your module `my_module.py`.

Inside your `my_module.py`

```
def A(sth):
    return pandas.module(sth)
```

And similarly for B